# Android drawables eclipse error

Tags: android, drawable, photo

I've a problem with my project. Eclipse gives me this mistakes

```
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] libpng error: Not a PNG file
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] ERROR: Failure processing PNG image C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\icon.png
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/background').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/address').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/web').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:64: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/phone').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:72: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/fax').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/email').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:91: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/back_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:126: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/back_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:175: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/play_btn').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/play_btn').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/play_btn').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\layout\main.xml:205: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/play_btn').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_about.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/about_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_about.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/about_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_freq.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/freq_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_freq.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/freq_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_live.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/play_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_live.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/play_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_programm.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/prog_burc').
[2011-07-20 10:34:21 - BurcFM] C:\Users\muhammed\workspace\BurcFM\res\drawable\tab_programm.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/prog_burc').
```

it's seems like it can't find the drawables, but there are all in drawable folder, I don't know what's wrong, I just deleted a background and put a new one instead, after that it start giving this error.

Comment: try to clean your project and check

Comment: first copy those file and past in assets folder in eclips

Comment: thanks people, i did that, but it didn't work, anyway i found the solution, you see in the errors it fails to process icon.png, i just replaced that one with android default icon, and it's fine now , anyway thank you all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure your icon.png is either 24 or 32 bit. Android doesn't handle 8 bit PNGs.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.For images, give the Image name without the extension. Worked for me. Maybe for any file.

Answer (score 0):

chk your style.xml there you must be define your style and you must have icon.png files in your specific layout folder. may be your error will be solved.

Comment: you don't need to have your own style to use drawables.